# No speed up in Separable Convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm implementing separable convolution to speed up 2D Gaussian convolution.

```
clear all;
close all;

im = randi([0,255],1024,1024);

win = 7;
window = fspecial('gaussian',win,win/6);

[U, S, V] = svd(window);
v = U(:,1) * sqrt(S(1,1));
h = V(:,1)' * sqrt(S(1,1));

out1 = filter2(window, im);
out2 = filter2(h, filter2(v, im));
norm(out1 - out2)

tic
for i = 1:1000
    out1 = filter2(window, im);
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:1000
    out2 = filter2(h, filter2(v, im));
end
toc
```

The separable version is supposed to be faster by win*win/(win + win) = 2.5 times, but it is actually slower:

```
ans =
2.6250e-12

Elapsed time is 5.486270 seconds.
Elapsed time is 8.769868 seconds.
```

Was there any hidden implementation inside filter2?

Comment: You're making twice as many calls to `filter2` in the second loop...it seems like this is the expected result.

Comment: Please always read the source code before asking this kind of questions.. what makes you think that X should be faster than Y if you have no idea how Y works?

Comment: `conv2` has a [three-input version for separable kernels](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/). Maybe that will be faster. You may need to flip some of the inputs to match the result of `filter2` (`filter2` computes correlation, not convolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you look at the source code of `filter2`, you can see that it is already implemented using the same separable SVD approach. This is the gist of what `filter2` does in your case (but you really should just step through the code):

```
[U, S, V] = svd(window,'econ');
v = U(:,1) * sqrt(S(1,1));
h = V(:,1)' * sqrt(S(1,1));
out2 = conv2(v, h, im, 'same');
```

What you do is the same, but instead of using a more efficient single call `conv2(v, h, im, 'same')`, you end up doing recursive call `conv2(conv2(im, v, 'same'), h, 'same')`, which is clearly what makes it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's implementation of the built-in `conv` set of functions (including `conv2`) is sub-optimal. You can read about it (and the workarounds) here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/convolution-performance.

The basic idea is to use either the convolution theorem or a C++-based MEX implementation, or preferably both, as used by Bruno Luong's ***[convfft](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution)*** utility.